# Confusion with integration of electric field of infinite line charge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, integration, coulombs-law

I'm trying to understand the formula for electric field of an infinite line charge, having charge density $\lambda$.

[image]

For such a charge distribution, electric field in y direction ($E_y$) should be zero because of symmetry. So the electric field must equal the x electric field ($E = E_x$)

However, when trying to integrate both $E$ and $E_x$ i am getting different results, so im doing something wrong here.

This is how I'm doing it:
$$dE = \frac{\lambda \, d\theta}{4\pi\epsilon_0r_0} $$
$$dE_x = \frac{\lambda \, cos\theta \, d\theta}{4\pi\epsilon_0r_0}$$
integrating both sides gives:-
$$E_x = \frac{\lambda}{2\pi\epsilon_0r_0}$$
and
$$dE_y = \frac{\lambda \, sin\theta \, d\theta}{4\pi\epsilon_0r_0} $$
integrating both sides gives $E_y = 0$

So the total electric field should be $E = E_x = \frac{\lambda}{2\pi\epsilon_0r_0}$

But if i directly integrate $dE = \frac{\lambda \, d\theta}{4\pi\epsilon_0r_0}$ then i get:-
$$E = \frac{\lambda}{4\pi\epsilon_0r_0} \int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2} d\theta$$
$$E = \frac{\lambda \, \pi}{4\pi\epsilon_0r_0}$$

So am i doing the integration wrong or applying the limits wrong, or is it something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add two vectors together, you can't simply add their magnitudes to find the magnitude of the result. You must add them component-wise, and then compute the magnitude at the end.

The same is true if you add $3$ vectors, $10$ vectors, or $10^{10}$ vectors. You are *integrating*, so you are in fact adding an infinite number of infinitesimal vectors together, but the same idea holds true.